# RDP can't connect to a known working 32 bit Server 2003

Tags: remote-desktop

Running Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, brand new system.

RDP can't connect to a known working 32 bit Server 2003

If I go to my XP Pro PC it works correctly.

Does anyone have a good to go KNOWN solution?

I need it for Work.

Thanks many times over in advance.

Doug
.

Comment: What message do you get when you try to connect? Are you connecting via IP address or DNS address? By what means are you configuring the network address, and is it known to be working correctly otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Thanks John for the reply.

I tried both ways. Yes, the server works, I called a fellow employee and he could get in on an XP computer.

Solution: I had to prepend the name of the computer that my logon account is on:

```
xcomputer\myID
```

That worked and I am back on schedule.